# python function calling from java import error pexpect

Tags: python, pexpect, jython-2.5

When I invoke python function in File `Scripts/IEEE 802.1ag/Python/CFMTestCases.py` by using

```
java PythonInterpreter()
```

it raise the following error:

```
Exception in thread "MainThread" Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "Scripts/IEEE 802.1ag/Python/CFMTestCases.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pexpect 
ImportError: No module named pexpect
Java Result: 1
```

I'm using jython2.5 and pexpect package version 2.3.

Comment: Is pexpect installed within Jython? What is `sys.path`?

Comment: my sys path is "Scripts/IEEE 802.1ag/Python/"

Comment: @ThomasK please tell me how to install pexpect within Jython and verify

Comment: Try copying pexpect.py into that folder.